# How to find all entries in a Lua table for Corona SDK display objects?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I followed [this tutorial in Corona SDK documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/tutorial/data/outputTable/index.html).

I am trying to print all the entries and subtables, and the entries in those subtables from a display object.

In Corona SDK, a display object is a Lua table and so I tried the basic things, as listed in the tutorial.

```
for k,v in pairs(myTable) do
    print( k,v )
end
```

There is also a fancier function that should output all subtables, namely:

```
local function printTable( t )

    local printTable_cache = {}

    local function sub_printTable( t, indent )

        if ( printTable_cache[tostring(t)] ) then
            print( indent .. "*" .. tostring(t) )
        else
            printTable_cache[tostring(t)] = true
            if ( type( t ) == "table" ) then
                for pos,val in pairs( t ) do
                    if ( type(val) == "table" ) then
                        print( indent .. "[" .. pos .. "] => " .. tostring( t ).. " {" )
                        sub_printTable( val, indent .. string.rep( " ", string.len(pos)+8 ) )
                        print( indent .. string.rep( " ", string.len(pos)+6 ) .. "}" )
                    elseif ( type(val) == "string" ) then
                        print( indent .. "[" .. pos .. '] => "' .. val .. '"' )
                    else
                        print( indent .. "[" .. pos .. "] => " .. tostring(val) )
                    end
                end
            else
                print( indent..tostring(t) )
            end
        end
    end

    if ( type(t) == "table" ) then
        print( tostring(t) .. " {" )
        sub_printTable( t, "  " )
        print( "}" )
    else
        sub_printTable( t, "  " )
    end
end
```

But neither of these actually print out all the entries in these tables. If I create a simple rectangle and try to use either of the functions, I only get two tables but I know that there's more there:

```
local myRectangle = display.newRect( 0, 0, 120, 40 )
for k,v in pairs(myRectangle) do
    print( k,v ) -- prints out "_class table, _proxy userdata"
end
print( myRectangle.x, myRectangle.width ) -- but this prints out "0, 120"

-- But if I were to add something to the table, then the loop finds that as well, e.g.

local myRectangle = display.newRect( 0, 0, 120, 40 )
myRectangle.secret = "hello"
for k,v in pairs(myRectangle) do
    print( k,v ) -- prints out "_class table, _proxy userdata, secret hello"
end
```

So, how can I print out everything included in a display object? Clearly these two approaches don't get the entries in the main display object table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can't, as you may have a metatable associated with that table that will generate results for fields "on the fly". In this case you get back something like a ShapeObject that provides methods like `fill`, `path`, `setFillColor` and others, but these methods are hidden behind a userdata object. It also provides inheritance, so there are some fields you can query that "belong" to other classes. You can use pairs/ipairs to get the list of keys in the table, which is what you get in your example (and setting `secret` adds a new key to the table).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding properties (not methods) of display object - display objects in Corona have special property `displayObject._properties` [Documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/properties.html)

`_properties` will return string, so you have two approaches of printing it:

```lua
local myRectangle = display.newRect( 0, 0, 120, 40 )

-- Approach 1:
-- Prettify here to make better readability to json
local json = require("json")
print("myRectangle._properties: ", json.prettify( myRectangle._properties ) )

-- Approach 2:
local json = require("json")
local myRectangleProps = json.decode(myRectangle._properties) -- I skipped error handling here, because there shouldn't be any
for k,v in pairs(myRectangleProps) do
    print( k,v ) -- prints x 0, width 120, etc
end
```

Comment: That's one way of getting more information, but it doesn't reveal everything. It only reveals specific values that the developers of Corona think you may likely need. Most things still remain under the hood, like physics body, vertices or fill related information.